# Scala: Is it a closure?

Tags: scala, closures

I want to know does my code represent a `closure concept`?

```
object Closure {
  val fun = (x: Int) => x + 1
  def clj = (y: Int) => y * fun(y)
}
```

Here is my runner code.

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val c = Closure
    val result = c.clj(10)
    println(result)
  }
}
```

Suppose, the closure code is

```
def clj = (y: Int) => y * fun(y)
```

Or maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't, because it doesn't *close over* anything.

This would be a closure:

```
object Foo {
  def clj(a: Int) = { (b: Int) => a + b }
}
```

This is:

- An `object` called `Foo` ...
- that contains a function `clj()` ...
- that returns *another* function.

The returned inner function captures (or *closes over*) the value of `a` at the time `clj()` is called, conceptually keeping it alive.

Thus:

```
val f1 = Foo.clj(10) // returns a function that adds 10 to whatever is passed
f1(100)              // => 110
```

The Wikipedia entry on closures actually contains a decent description of the concept.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: the example you gave is Currying, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

As I see the closure concept, yes, your code in `clj` represents a closure since it refers an external function `fun`, a so-called "environment" in closure terms.